# How to bind a tree object to a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have 2 different classes (A and B) which are linked each other to make something similar to a binary tree like this:

```
public class A
{
    public B instanceB1;      
    public B instanceB2;
}
```

```
public class B
{
    public A instanceA;

    public int Min;
    public int Max;   
}
```

How can I make a bind of this tree where only "Min" and "Max" of leaf/last nodes are displayed in a datagrid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make all those fields properties, so you can bind to them. Then write trivial recursive methods to walk the tree and return a flat list of leaf nodes. I'm assuming that "leaf/last" just means "leaf".

```
public class A
{
    public B instanceB1 { get; set; }
    public B instanceB2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<B> EnumerateLeaves
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var child in instanceB1.EnumerateLeaves
                                      .Concat(instanceB2.EnumerateLeaves))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }

}

public class B
{
    public A instanceA { get; set; }

    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<B> EnumerateLeaves
    {
        get
        {
            if (instanceA == null)
            {
                yield return this;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var child in instanceA.EnumerateLeaves)
                    yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind to them:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRootItem.EnumerateLeaves}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Min}" Header="Min" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Max}" Header="Max" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```